# Which pronoun to use in a relative clause?

Tags: pronoun, relative-clause, subordinate-clause

What is the correct way to refer to the object in a subordinate clause?

> Haben sie mehr von der blauen Farbe, **das/die/der** Sie genutzt haben, um die Tür zu malen?

Comment: You're right, I meant 'object'!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's

> ... mehr von der blauen Farbe, *die* ...

Be careful, though: In German *malen* usually means to "render in color". It's what a painter, an artist does. If you're referring to a new coat of paint for the door, you better use *streichen*. Likewise, *genutzt*, while perfectly understandable, is not idiomatic in this case. Use ***be**nutzt*:

> Haben Sie noch etwas von der blauen Farbe, die Sie benutzt haben, um die Tür zu streichen?
>   Haben Sie noch mehr von der blauen Farbe, mit der Sie die Tür gestrichen haben?

Answer (score 3):

Since "die Farbe" is feminine, you use a feminine relative pronoun. Since this pronoun is the direct object of the relative clause, you use it at the accusative (which in this case is the same as nominative): "die".

> Haben Sie noch etwas von der blauen Farbe, ***die*** Sie benutzt haben, um die Tür zu streichen?

Comment: General rule: use the pronoun that fits the subject's article.

Comment: @Raphael but there the subject is *Sie*, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Raphael... do you mean grammatical subject? Because if so, your statement is wrong.